# Systemd service using screen: 'No screen session found'

Tags: minecraft, boot, systemd, gnu-screen

I'm trying to setup a minecraft server for my kid and screen is giving me fits.  I've been following [this](https://teilgedanken.de/Blog/post/setting-up-a-minecraft-server-using-systemd/) tutorial and I've already consulted [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861309/screen-needs-mode-777-with-systemd-service) AskUbuntu answer.  I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04.5 x64.  I have created the following Service file and linked it to /etc/systemd/system/minecraft.service.

```
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft Server
Documentation=

Wants=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
User=minecraft
Group=minecraft
Nice=5
EnvironmentFile=-/var/minecraft/unit.conf
KillMode=none
SuccessExitStatus=0 1

ProtectHome=true
ProtectSystem=full
PrivateDevices=true
NoNewPrivileges=true
PrivateTmp=true
InaccessibleDirectories=/root /sys /srv -/opt /media -/lost+found
ReadWriteDirectories=/var/minecraft/server /usr/bin/screen
WorkingDirectory=/var/minecraft/server
#ExecStartPre= /usr/bin/screen -dmS Minecraft
ExecStart= /usr/bin/screen -dm -S Minecraft '/usr/bin/java -Xmx1500M -Xms1024M -jar /var/minecraft/server/craftbukkit-1.13.jar'
ExecStop=/usr/bin/screen -S minecraft -p 0 -X stuff "stop^M"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I monitor the service startup, I get the following in the journalctl logs:

```
Aug 05 14:55:41 spigot-1 systemd[1]: Started Minecraft Server.
Aug 05 14:55:41 spigot-1 screen[9869]: No screen session found.
```

Per the SO post I referenced, I already changed the permissions in /var/run/screen.  This is the current setup:

```
root@spigot-1:/var/minecraft/server# ls -alR /var/run/screen/
/var/run/screen/:
total 0
drwxrwxrwx  4 root      root       80 Aug  5 14:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root      root      860 Aug  5 14:11 ..
drwx------  2 minecraft minecraft  40 Aug  5 14:55 S-minecraft
drwx------  2 root      root       40 Aug  5 14:50 S-root

/var/run/screen/S-minecraft:
total 0
drwx------ 2 minecraft minecraft 40 Aug  5 14:55 .
drwxrwxrwx 4 root      root      80 Aug  5 14:12 ..

/var/run/screen/S-root:
total 0
drwx------ 2 root root 40 Aug  5 14:50 .
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 80 Aug  5 14:12 ..
```

** Debug Notes **
You'll see the commented ExecStartPre command in there... all that happens if I try to start the screen session with that command is I get a second 'No screen session found' error.

I can launch the server from the command line using 'screen -dmS Minecraft [..]' and reattach.  I can do this both as root and as the 'minecraft' user.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Judging from the close votes, you should probably have posted this on unix.stackexchange.com, but see my answer anyway.

Comment: Why do you use `screen`? You will find program output in the `journal`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Ubuntu to hand, but I tried something similar on Fedora 24 and had a similar error. To investigate I added an `strace` to the `screen` command and removed `PrivateTmp` so that I could get the trace output.

```
ExecStart=/bin/strace -o /tmp/s -f screen -dm -S me bash -c 'sleep 999'
```

In the output I found that at the end, `screen` was trying to open a pseudo-tty and failed to do so:

```
open("/dev/ptmx", O_RDWR)         = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
...
write(1, "No more PTYs.\r\nSorry, could not "..., 52) = 52
```

I added some `ls -l /dev` commands to the Unit to see what the effect of the `PrivateDevices=true` option had been. There was indeed a `/dev/ptmx` file, but unlike my real `/dev` it was a symbolic link to `/dev/pts/ptmx`, instead of just being the special character device. For some reason on my system I have:

```
$ ls -l /dev/ptmx /dev/pts/ptmx
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty  5, 2 Aug  6 14:29 /dev/ptmx
c--------- 1 root root 5, 2 Jun 27 08:29 /dev/pts/ptmx
```

(This is probably a bug depending on the version of systemd and udev.)
So when `/dev/ptmx` is replaced in the private namespace by a symbolic link to `/dev/pts/ptmx`, you can no longer open a new pty.  A simple fix for testing was `sudo chmod a+rw /dev/pts/ptmx` which indeed made the Unit work and start the `screen` process.

This may not be the case for you, but you could undertake a similar debug method to try to find the problem.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try this as soon as my work schedule allows.  If it works I'll mark the answer as accepted.